# Why sometimes laravel doesn't react?

Tags: laravel-4

Sometimes when i bring changes in CSS or in HTML contents or maybe controllers, i refresh many times but the change not applies in the app and it still looks like the past. Does anyone faced this problem? or how i'm going to solve this issue?

Comment: Disable OPCache if you have it enabled, it seems to cache Blade templates (that's good) but serves stale templates after the files were modified.

Comment: And to make Laravel discover new controllers you need to run `php artisan dump-autoload`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not using PSR-4 autoloading. You'll need to reflect new controllers with `$ composer dump-autoload -o` (note the -o optimises the class-mapping).

Other than that, are you behind any caching drivers?

Answer (score 0):

For good measure, change the following in your **development** cache config(\app\config\development\cache.php) (Don't have a development folder? [Read this](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/configuration#environment-configuration)) as well:

```
<?php

return array(

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Cache Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default cache "driver" that will be used when
    | using the Caching library. Of course, you may use other drivers any
    | time you wish. This is the default when another is not specified.
    |
    | Supported: "file", "database", "apc", "memcached", "redis", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => 'file',
```

Laravel will store all your cache files in the following folder: `app\storage\cache` and view caches in: `app\storage\view`. Clear both when necessary.